# How can I use Regex to determine if a string has either a number, equation symbols, or a period in it?

Tags: regex, javascript, string

I created this new custom console api while I was bored, and I created a feature which allows you to change a variables value.

**If your curious about the console api, heres a live pen:** https://codepen.io/SkylerSpark/pen/JjPZGLP

its suprisingly complicated, but im currently using this Regexp to determine if its a number or string:

`/^\d+$/`

```js
function conLogEditVar() {
 var a1 = cmd.input;
 var a2 = a1.split("=", 2);
 var a3 = a2[1];
 if (/^\d+$/.test(a3) == true) {
  window[a2[0]] = Number(a2[1]);

...
```

The issue is that this only looks for 0-9, and i want it to look for 0-9, and any of these chars: **(So that people can set their var's value to a number equation of course)**

% * / + - .

I tried this equation, but I think it only looks for strings that have ALL of the chars in them, making this useless:

`/^\d+\-\+\/\%\*\.$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
  if (eq.match(/^[0-9+%/*.-]+$/))
```

it will only allow 0-9 and +*%.-,
for your code try

```
if (/^[0-9+%/*.-]+$/.test(a3) == true) 
{
  window[a2[0]] = Number(a2[1]);
}
```